# Using AJAX and a huge text file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a huge text file and I am going to pick 5 aléatoir ligne to read and store the content into an array but when I'm testing the response that I get with an `alert()` it doesn't show all the content.

```
function loadWords(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "dico/francais.txt");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE && xhr.status == 200){
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

is there any other way more powerful to get the job done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put massive data into `alert();`

`alert` will always strip it after a certain length (sometimes when your screen resolution is not big enough to display it all etc.)

What you could do, is to put all of it into a `textarea` in HTML in order to take a look at it.